# Proper method to timing how long a sorting algorithm takes

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, time

(Using Java)

I'm testing sorting arrays to see literally how fast different sorting arrays take.  I want to weed out the erroneous times, so ideally I would like to start a timer, run the sort in a loop of say 100 times, stop the timer, then divide by 100 to get a pretty accurate measure.

The problem is if I were to loop the same array, it'll sort properly the first time, then each sort after, it'll keep sorting the already sorted array, which isn't what I want.

Maybe I'm missing an obvious solution, but is there any way I can make it keep sorting the same initial randomized array?

I thought about reassigning the newly sorted array back to the initial random array each time, but that would mess up my timer..

thanks for any suggestions

what i would like to do:

```
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i=0; i<cntr; i++) {
            sort array
        }
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        time = (endTime - startTime)/cntr;
```

Comment: FYI, timing things like this accurately is extremely tricky with the JIT.  Use a tool like [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) that knows how to deal with this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a copy before you start sorting, and then copy from that stored copy into the array being sorted in each iteration of the loop.

```
int[] toBeSorted = new int[10000];
// fill the array with data
int[] copied = new int[10000];
System.arrayCopy(toBeSorted, 0, copied, 0, copied.length);
// prepare the timer, but do not start it
for (int = 0 ; i != 100 ; i++) {
    System.arrayCopy(copied, 0, toBeSorted, 0, copied.length);
    // Now the toBeSorted is in its initial state
    // Start the timer
    Arrays.sort(toBeSorted);
    // Stop the timer before the next iteration
}
```

Comment: if i understand correctly, the copying from the stored copy after each sort would affect the timer (timing in nano & milliseconds).  unless i'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @user1189352 I added the comment to mention that the timer needs to be stopped and re-started between sorts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `System.currentTimeMillis()` method to get the current time then subtract when the method finishes executing.

```
long totalRuntime = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   sortArrays()
   long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

   totalRuntime += (endTime - startTime);
}

System.out.println("Algorithm X on average took " 
                    + totalRuntime/100 + " milliseconds);
```

If you want to do this X times just keep a counter for each algorithm and increment. Then you can divide by the total number of runs at the end and compare.

Comment: ya that's what im pretty much doing, BUT i want to loop it 100+ times

Comment: i see your edit, but I believe what it will be doing after the 2nd sort is just keep sorting an already sorted array.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would stop and start the timer in between each run of the algorithm you're testing, adding up the individual times and then dividing by the number of runs. That way any "setup time" isn't included because the timer isn't running during the setup.

Comment: ah ya i know that much, the only reason i couldn't think of a solution is because after the 1st sort, it'll keep sorting an already sorted array

Comment: @user1189352 yes, but once you've stopped the timer in between trials, you can spend as much time as you want re-initializing the array to be sorted because the clock isn't running.

Answer (score 1):

Go with something like this

```
new array equals random array,
start timer
sort new array
stop timer
add time to your list of times
repeat until necessary
```

As long as you copy the original array each time, you will never sort the original one

Comment: thx for the suggestion, but as stated in my OP, the problem why i can't do this is because after the 1st sort, i'd be sorting an already sorted array

Comment: That's what the first line is `new array equals random array` copy the original array into a new one each time, and sort the new one, that way you always maintain the original array in unsorted order. It's the same as dasblinken, just pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

put the sorting algorithm in a function and keep calling the function with the same again and again and passing the array to the function after cloning it using the clone method.
You can call the current time function and print it out every time you run the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to blow memory, then just make 100 (or however many) copies of the same array before you start timing. If you're not, then time sorting and copying together, and then time just copying to see approximately how much of your sorting + copying time was spent copying.

Also, sidenote: look into using a benchmarking framework like [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) instead of doing your own "manual" benchmarking. It's easier, and they've solved a lot of problems that you might not even know are going on that could screw up your timings.

Comment: ah ya, i would prefer to find an efficient way of doing so, good thinking though and thx for the suggestion